# Quem foi convidado para o beta privado?

Tags: suporte

Conversei com algumas pessoas que estavam comprometidas com a proposta do site e me afirmaram que não receberam nem a notificação de novembro que o site seria lançado, muito menos o convite para iniciar o beta. Claro que eu conto com a possibilidade deles terem recebido em em uma conta que não estão usando, ter caindo no *spam*m etc. Mas também pode ter havido algum problema ou ter havido alguma seleção.

Houve uma seleção? Qual o critério?

Se a pessoa foi convidada e não consegue acessar o e-mail com o convite, existe alguma possibilidade dela fazer o cadastro e login no site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não houve seleção. Todos os emails que nós tinhamos na Area 51 receberam a primeira mensagem (que pedia a confirmação do email). E todos que confirmaram o email receberam o email de ontem...

Todo mundo que está na proposta vai receber o email do da Area 51 ainda hoje a tarde. Aí não vai ter ninguém faltando.

Comment: Como vai funcionar o beta? Posso convidar mais gente? Divulgar em listas?

Comment: Na página inicial tem um painel na direita "Convidar colegas especialistas". Testei enviar uma convite a um outro email meu e recebi um link semelhante ao do email da stackexchange.

Comment: @Piovezan Pode convidar à vontade. Mas sempre tenha em mente que esse também é um beta no sentido técnico. O sistema ainda não foi totalmente localizado pra PT, então ainda existem bugs

Comment: @Gabe Legal, obrigado. Mas mesmo assim queria uma confirmação disso, pois o email que foi enviado aos participantes orienta a convidar somente depois do período de beta privado.